# Flash - Sound - Embending external sounds in the swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hello Im creating a game , that have more than 200 sounds , so I cannot just put the sounds in my libray in flash and then instanciate them as class and play them. Because the sound it will play when I click one object is not always the same.

I have this function to play background sound , where enters the name of the song I wanna to be played :

public function startMusicBack(music:String):void{

```
        var musicback:Sound = new Sound();
        var bgChannel:SoundChannel;
        var bgTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1); 

        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(music); 



        try {

            musicback.load(req);

            //parar todos os sons
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            // vou transformar o som para ele ficar mais baixo
            bgTransform.volume = .05;
            //faço o play do som mas meto num soun
            bgChannel= musicback.play(0,999,bgTransform);
        }
        catch (err:Error) {
            trace(err.message);
        }
```

}

Ok this worked fine until I tryied do a export of the swf file , and then I got messages of error because of the path to the music is not correct .

Ok my question is , how can I embed the past with the  sounds in the swf or how can I call musics in library of flash in runtime  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed sounds directly into your SWF using the Embed tag:

```
// the path here is relative to the *File*, not the SWF
[Embed(source = "../../../../../assets/someSound.mp3", mimeType = "audio/mpeg")]
public var mySound:Class;
```

then you can create a new Sound as:

```
var s:Sound = new mySound;
```

Although, with 200 sounds, this'll probably make your SWF enormous and make your compile time a pain in the ass. For the problem that you're having, it just looks like the path to your music file is wrong. If you had a project layout like this:

```
parentFolder
    - assets
        - mySound.mp3
    - bin
        - output.swf
    - src
        - subFolder
            - Main.as
```

Then in your main class, you pass the path to the sound as relative to your ****SWF**** file (i.e. output.swf), so call your function like:

```
this.startMusicBack( "../mySound.mp3" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the sounds are like 2 or 3kb maxim is like 1 second of sound compressed in mp3 of one word.. Im not hurry about that , but for me to embeded the 200 sound it will do a lot of work if I have do one by oñe.  About the path is wrong that is not he problem because I can play the sounds when testing on when creating the swf file and playing it in the parent folder, my problem is I want to play this in iphone/android when creating the file form them is possible to add this external files?????

Comment: ok I see what is the problem, I just added the sound past in the publishing setting and then it is working .. Ok tahnks for your help..

Comment: If your sounds are small, then it shouldn't be took much of a hassle. Create a tool class to generate the file for you (I do this all the time for stuff like localisation etc). How easy this will be depends on the names of your files. Just loop through your sounds and concat a big string, then save that out with the `File` class

Comment: Using the [Embed] tag wouldn't be such a bad idea even for 200 sounds: This could be a separate SWF precompiled. You only ever need to compile this sounds.swf ONCE - and then you could actually [Embed] the sounds.swf and instantiate your sounds from the YouSWFBytesLoader.contentLoaderInfo.getDefinition("YourSoundName"). OR, load the sounds.swf at runtime and show a progress bar of it loading :)